# Хотел бы уточнить пару вопросов в коде где используется прокси

Tags: javascript, proxy-class

```
    let products = new Proxy([
  { name: 'Firefox', type: 'browser' },
  { name: 'SeaMonkey', type: 'browser' },
  { name: 'Thunderbird', type: 'mailer' }
],
{
  get: function(obj, prop) {
    // Стандартное возвращение значения; prop обычно является числом
    if (prop in obj) {
      return obj[prop];
    }

    // Получение количества продуктов; псевдоним products.length
    if (prop === 'number') {
      return obj.length;
    }

    let result, types = {};

    for (let product of obj) {
      if (product.name === prop) {
        result = product;
      }
      if (types[product.type]) {
        types[product.type].push(product);
      } else {
        types[product.type] = [product];
      }
    }

    // Получение продукта по имени
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }

    // Получение продуктов по типу
    if (prop in types) {
      return types[prop];
    }

    // Получение типов продуктов
    if (prop === 'types') {
      return Object.keys(types);
    }

    return undefined;
  }
});
```

Данный прокси расширяет массив дополнительными возможностями.

```
for (let product of obj) {
          if (product.name === prop) {
            result = product;
          }
```

Как я понял в цикле for в прокси в первом if проверяется если введенное свойство является названием браузера и если это так то итерируемый объект добавляется в result.

```
for (let product of obj) {
          if (product.name === prop) {
            result = product;
          }
          if (types[product.type]) {
            types[product.type].push(product);
          } else {
            types[product.type] = [product];
          }
        }
```

Во втором if проверяется есть ли в объекте types тип итерируемого объекта и если такого нет то он добавляется в этот объект types. Затем этот объект types используется чтобы вывести продукт по его типу если введенное свойство является типом. Я правильно понял?

P.S Вот кстати примеры вывода

```
console.log(products[0]); // { name: 'Firefox', type: 'browser' }
console.log(products['Firefox']); // { name: 'Firefox', type: 'browser' }
console.log(products['Chrome']); // undefined
console.log(products.browser); // [{ name: 'Firefox', type: 'browser' }, { name: 'SeaMonkey', type: 'browser' }]
console.log(products.types); // ['browser', 'mailer']
console.log(products.number); // 3
```

Comment: в чем именно заключается вопрос?

Comment: @Grundy Правильно ли автор понимает как работает этот код? :)